# Which daemons can be stopped from loading at boot time?

Tags: boot, services

Below is list obtained from `chkconfig` utility. I want to know that which of these daemons can be stopped safely without losing any additional features ?

```
acpi-support              0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
acpid                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
alsa-mixer-save           0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
anacron                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
apache2                   0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
apparmor                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
apport                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
atd                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
atieventsd                0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
avahi-daemon              0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
binfmt-support            0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
bluetooth                 0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
bootlogd                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
brltty                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
clamav-daemon             0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
clamav-freshclam          0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
console-setup             0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
cron                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
cups                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
dbus                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
dmesg                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
dns-clean                 0:off  1:on   2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
failsafe-x                0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
fancontrol                0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
gdm                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
grub-common               0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
hostname                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
hwclock                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
hwclock-save              0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
irqbalance                0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
jetty                     0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
kerneloops                0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
killprocs                 0:off  1:on   2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
lm-sensors                0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
module-init-tools         0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
mysql                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
network-interface         0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
network-interface-security  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
network-manager           0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
networking                0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
ondemand                  0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
pcmciautils               0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
plymouth                  0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
plymouth-log              0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
plymouth-splash           0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
plymouth-stop             0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
pppd-dns                  0:off  1:on   2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
procps                    0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
pulseaudio                0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
rc.local                  0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
rcS                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
rsync                     0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
rsyslog                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
saned                     0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
screen-cleanup            0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
sendsigs                  0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
speech-dispatcher         0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
stop-bootlogd             0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
stop-bootlogd-single      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
sudo                      0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
tmux-cleanup              0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
udev                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
udev-finish               0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
udevmonitor               0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
udevtrigger               0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
ufw                       0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
umountfs                  0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
umountnfs.sh              0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
umountroot                0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
unattended-upgrades       0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
urandom                   0:on   1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on 
vboxdrv                   0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
vboxweb-service           0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
x11-common                0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  S:on
```

Comment: It depends on what you are using the PC (Or server as it looks like) for.

For example if you do not want to print ever again, cusp has to go.
Not using virtualbox?, vbox has to go.
No firewall? then ufw goes away too.

You can imagine the rest. You need to add what are you using the PC for at least. If i was using that as a server for example, i would not need pulseaudio, the whole plymouth with the splashy stuff and the gdm desktop. But if you ARE  using all that with a normal desktop then it is more tough since you got mixed things (desktop + server).

Comment: I am using Dell Inspiron N5010 Notebook. I use virtualbox , but I dont use it for printing, and I dont use plymouth either, I like to see text booting.

Comment: You say "which of these daemons can be stopped safely without losing any additional features". Any single service can have a good use. You need to refine what you really want.

Comment: Maybe a better question is: What services are absolutely crucial for basic system functionality? Where basic system functionality includes Gnome + unprotected internet.

Comment: @user4124 What I really want is to make the booting process as fast as possible. @djeikyb Yeah thats exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a dumb answer, but like everyone in the comments has pointed out, unnecessary is relative. It completely depends on your system and what you want to do with it. I don't know that anyone can give you a perfect answer.

The best thing, if you really want to streamline your boot process, is to study each of those daemons. Google each one of them, find out what they do. Then disable it. Try to boot. Use your system, see what works, what doesn't. Can you live without that daemon? Did it break your boot process? Re-enable it if you need, move to the next one.

What's great about this is you'll break your system several times. In turn, you'll have to figure out how to fix it, and you'll have an even better understanding of how Ubuntu and linux work. Then you can come back here and answer lots of questions ;p

Oh, and, backup. Always backup. Or you could take Luri's sensible advice and run a test install in your virtual machine.

Comment: As an improvement to this soultion, I'd suggest you set up a Virtual Machine and do the daemons testing on it... Then, you'll have no risk of "breaking" your (real) system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and @luri thanks for the suggestion.